# Close edit menu when 3D touch in textfield swift

Tags: swift, uitextview, 3dtouch, uimenucontroller

[image]

How to close this menu when 3D touch click in textfiled using swift

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean whenever long touch press this menu open but when 3d touch i want to close this menu.

Comment: So you don´t want to show this menu on long press, is that what you want to do?

Comment: no i want to show this menu in long press but i want to close when 3d touch press.

Comment: Isn´t that automatically closed when you force touch?

Comment: no it's not close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create one none case which return false and call that case when 3D touch start and call select case when 3D touch ended.**

```
override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool
        {
            switch self.currentState {
            case .select:
                if action == #selector(select(_:)) || action == #selector(selectAll(_:))
                {
                    return true
                }
            case .copy:
                if action == #selector(copy(_:))
                {
                    return true
                }
            case .paste:
                if action == #selector(paste(_:)) || action == #selector(select(_:)) || action == #selector(selectAll(_:))
                {
                    return true
                }
            case .none:
                return false
            }
            return false
        }
```